# Material UI ButtonGroup breaks when adding href to Button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Everything is in the title. Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicbuttongroup-material-demo-forked-2eloiw?file=/demo.js:280-295) with reproduction !

When using MUI's ButtonGroup, the layout is fine with three "regular" buttons:

```
<ButtonGroup variant="contained" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
  <Button>One</Button>
  <Button>Two</Button>
  <Button>Three</Button>
</ButtonGroup>
```

Result:

[image: ButtonGroup example]

But as soon as we add an href to one of the buttons, it breaks the layout, like so:

```
<ButtonGroup variant="contained" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
  <Button href="test.com">One</Button>
  <Button>Two</Button>
  <Button>Three</Button>
</ButtonGroup>
```

Result:

[image: broken ButtonGroup]

Is there any way to fix this ? I don't want to have to use the trick of onClick and location.replace or location.href...

Also, maybe I should post this as an issue on [MUI's GitHub](https://github.com/mui/material-ui)? I'm guessing only if it is relevant and not fixable, but there are so many I doubt they would see it.

Comment: I remember there being a `component` prop that you can set to 'a', but it may be advantageous to put a link and set *that* component to a `Button` element and try it that way.

Comment: I think the second way wouldn't work since the `Button` components have to be at the root of the `ButtonGroup` component to work? If there is a link in the middle it most likely will break too, but I can try thanks!

Comment: setting the component prop to 'button' effectively makes it a button. It inherits all of those props.

Answer (score -1):

Use the prop  `LinkComponent="button"`:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import ButtonGroup from "@mui/material/ButtonGroup";

export default function BasicButtonGroup() {
  return (
    <ButtonGroup variant="contained" aria-label="outlined primary button group">
      <Button LinkComponent="button" href="test.com">
        One
      </Button>
      <Button>Two</Button>
      <Button>Three</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
  );
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basicbuttongroup-material-demo-forked-43pmhn?file=/demo.js:0-430

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Adding `LinkComponent="button"` works for the layout but makes the link unusable, sorry that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does not work in the link that you sent.

Comment: Clicking the link does not work